# Can't add object likes attribute in function

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc, angularjs-scope

I have problem,i have one entity which have other,but when i try to add object like atribute when i try to add this entity in db i have error that is object null.

I accept object in routh likes this:

```
   when('/dodajPregled/:entry2',{
       templateUrl: 'dodajPregled.htm',
       controller: 'myCtrl3'
   }).
```

This is form :

```
olest: <input type="text" ng-model="pregled.bolest" required>
  Dijagnoza Name: <input type="text" ng-model="pregled.dijagnoza" required>
  Lekovi: <input type="text" ng-model="pregled.lekovi" required>
 id: <input type="text" ng-model="pregled.id" required>
  <button ng-click="add(pregled)">add</button>
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl3',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $scope.pacijent=$routeParams.entry2;
    $scope.odgovor=this;
    $scope.add=function(pregled){


        pregled2=pregled;
        pregled2.pacijent=$scope.pacijent;

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/fizijatar/pregled2/',pregled2)
              .then(
                      function(response){
                         $scope.odgovor= response.data;
                      }, 
                      function(response){
                          console.error('Error while creating user');

                          $scope.odgovor= response.data;
                      }
              );
    };


}
);
```

When i print `$scope.pacijent=$routeParams.entry2;` they show me current object which i wan t to add to pregled likes property

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is change:

```
pregled2=pregled;
```

to

```
var pregled2=pregled;
```

Here is a plunker outlining this. If you set the input field when in "Home" view, when you navigate to dodajPregled, the :entry2 param will be that of the input field content. It is also displayed at the bottom of the page.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7hjBW483nDXRWE6SFv5A?p=preview